# npm install just do nothing on Kudu

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, kudu, tedious

This morning I run `npm install` and the `node_modules` was created with all the files in it.

Then a few hour after, I run the same command same package.json file... no error, `node_modules` was created, but empty!?

ANy ideas?

Here my package.json, very regular generated via an npm init adding `tedious` package.

```
{
  "name": "tedious",
  "version": "2.1.1",
  "description": "COnnect to Database",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious#readme"
}
```

Comment: That's when running manually in Kudu console? What does `npm --version` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `dependencies` in your `package.json`.

You'll need to add the npm modules you want to install into the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`, and then run `npm install` to download them.

```
"dependencies": {
    "tedious": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    ...................
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the command `npm install <package_name> --save` to do that.

Reference: [Using a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json).