# Kudu console hangs on npm install

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions, kudu

I'm trying to use Azure Functions and want to add some dependencies to my code, then I followed step provided [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management). After running `npm install` and waited for quite a long time, the Kudu console just seems to hang and do nothing. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404877/npm-install-just-do-nothing-on-kudu) but seems like I'm having a different problem.

Here is my `package.json`. Any ideas?

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents",
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3",
    "request": "^2.87.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function app is on Consumption plan, check your `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` in Application settings.

Npm installation hangs for 20m+ when node version is `6.5.0` on my side. After upgrading it to `8.11.1`, this installation costs 6~7 minutes. And on App service plan, it costs less than 7m even though node version is v6.x.

This duration is not much ideal either, as it's a limitation of Azure Files, which has latency with multiple small files, see [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/197#issuecomment-286614641). You can have a look at [Azure function pack](https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-functions-pack#azure-functions-pack) if needed.

**Use function pack**

1. (If you develop online, download app content first) Delete old functions online.
2. In your function app directory, `npm install` your packages locally.
3. `npm install -g azure-functions-pack` to install function pack tool.
4. `funcpack pack -c .` to place all the modules in a single file.
5. Go to `.funcpack` folder and upload all content inside through kudu.
6. Refresh your function app.